# Exporting dataRow to a csv

Tags: powershell, csv, powershell-2.0

I have run a MySQL Query, which has given me a resultset that I can work with.

However, I now need to export it to a CSV file.

If I run

```
$result1 | export-csv "c:\path\to\csv.csv"
```

I get a file with a single entry in the first cell only:

```
#TYPE System.Int32
```

But there should be apx 6000 rows.

If I do

```
$result1 | Get-member
```

I get:

```
TypeName: System.Int32

Name        MemberType Definition                                                                           
----        ---------- ----------                                                                           
CompareTo   Method     int CompareTo(System.Object value), int CompareTo(int value)                         
Equals      Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj), bool Equals(int obj)                                 
GetHashCode Method     int GetHashCode()                                                                    
GetType     Method     type GetType()                                                                       
GetTypeCode Method     System.TypeCode GetTypeCode()                                                        
ToString    Method     string ToString(), string ToString(string format), string ToString(System.IFormatP...


   TypeName: System.Data.DataRow

Name              MemberType            Definition                                                          
----              ----------            ----------                                                          
AcceptChanges     Method                System.Void AcceptChanges()                                         
BeginEdit         Method                System.Void BeginEdit()                                             
CancelEdit        Method                System.Void CancelEdit()                                            
ClearErrors       Method                System.Void ClearErrors()                                           
Delete            Method                System.Void Delete()                                                
EndEdit           Method                System.Void EndEdit()                                               
Equals            Method                bool Equals(System.Object obj)                                      
GetChildRows      Method                System.Data.DataRow[] GetChildRows(string relationName), System.D...
GetColumnError    Method                string GetColumnError(int columnIndex), string GetColumnError(str...
GetColumnsInError Method                System.Data.DataColumn[] GetColumnsInError()                        
GetHashCode       Method                int GetHashCode()                                                   
GetParentRow      Method                System.Data.DataRow GetParentRow(string relationName), System.Dat...
GetParentRows     Method                System.Data.DataRow[] GetParentRows(string relationName), System....
GetType           Method                type GetType()                                                      
HasVersion        Method                bool HasVersion(System.Data.DataRowVersion version)                 
IsNull            Method                bool IsNull(int columnIndex), bool IsNull(string columnName), boo...
RejectChanges     Method                System.Void RejectChanges()                                         
SetAdded          Method                System.Void SetAdded()                                              
SetColumnError    Method                System.Void SetColumnError(int columnIndex, string error), System...
SetModified       Method                System.Void SetModified()                                           
SetParentRow      Method                System.Void SetParentRow(System.Data.DataRow parentRow), System.V...
ToString          Method                string ToString()                                                   
Item              ParameterizedProperty System.Object Item(int columnIndex) {get;set;}, System.Object Ite...
CJ                Property              System.UInt64 CustomerJobId {get;set;}                              
End               Property              System.DateTime Endtime {get;set;}                                  
Name              Property              System.String Engineer {get;set;}                                   
JN                Property              System.String Jobname {get;set;}                                    
Start             Property              System.DateTime Starttime {get;set;}
```

What's the correct way to convert this to a CSV file?

---

`write-host $result1` gives me data similar to the below:

```
CJ            : 
JN            : 
Name          : Mr Smith
Start         : 
End           : 

CJ            : 987654321
JN            : 
Name          : Mr Jones
Starttime     : 29/09/2015 08:00:00
Endtime       : 29/09/2015 08:30:00
```

Comment: What does `$result1` look like in console? You can remove that definition line with `export-csv "c:\path\to\csv.csv" -NoTypeInformation` but that is not your real issue now. `$result1` just sounds like a number. Not an Object that `export-csv` would use.

Comment: cheers, I've added an example of what $result1 looks like

Comment: Can you show the code that loads `$result1`

Comment: That is two records? There is a problem there with the parameter set being different start vs starttime for example. They dont match. Is that a test data issue or is that the actual data.

Comment: sorry, it should say 'start' and 'end'

Comment: Try calling $result.Datarow and piping that to Export-CSV, that might also work.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a way to make this work, by creating a PSObject, and then converting that to CSV.

```
$a = 0
$data = @()
foreach($res in $result1)
    {
        if($a -eq 0)
            {
                #Do Nothing
            }
        else
            {
                $cj = $res.CJ
                $jn = $res.JN
                $en = $res.Name
                $st = $res.Start
                $et = $res.End

                #write-host "$cj,$jn,$en,$st,$et"

                $row = New-Object PSObject
                $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "CJ" -Value $cj -force
                $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "JN" -Value $jn -force
                $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Name" -Value $en -force
                $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Start" -Value $st -force
                $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "End" -Value $et -force

                $data += $row         
            }
         $a++   
    }

$data | Export-Csv "c:\path\to\csv.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```